# Database of synonym gradients

Tags: corpora, synonymy

I'm going to be analyzing tweets where I care about how confidently someone is expressing an idea.  So:

> X destroyed Y

Would be express greater confidence than

> X beat Y

About 9 months ago I found a site that had ranked the relative strength of similar verbs, but I dumbly didn't bookmark it; but I know such a list exits.

Is anyone aware of a database like this somewhere?  I've been searching for days.

Comment: This would be a great research question by itself, but lends itself to subjective ordinates that may not be statistically significant for everyone and may change over time.  Furthermore, an entire master's thesis could cover studying the gradients of only one word.  An entire database of researched gradients would be a significant accomplishment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project to induce verb-verb relations automatically using a pattern based approach a few years ago. 
The effort included gradient (or strength). I would recommend to take a look at:
http://demo.patrickpantel.com/demos/verbocean/.

I am not sure if it's still maintained, but it may be worthwhile to contact one of the authors of the paper on this:
Timothy Chklovski and Patrick Pantel. 2004. VERBOCEAN: Mining the Web for Fine-Grained Semantic Verb Relations. In Proceedings of Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing (EMNLP-04). pp. 33-40. Barcelona, Spain

Comment: Thank you, from their database, I can build an ordinal list that will work perfectly.